# ¿Qué tipo de dato utilizo para guardar una lista de cadenas en Django?

Tags: html5, postgresql, django-models

En una aplicación web de django con postgresql, necesito guardar un campo **Complementos** en la tabla de **Artículos**. Este campo será una lista de artículos ya existentes, que serán los complementos del artículo en cuestión, y se representarán en el DOM como una lista donde se podrán añadir o eliminar artículos.

En django está el validador **validate_comma_separated_integer_list** para un campo del tipo **CharField** que comprueba el valor como una lista de números enteros, pero no encuentro nada similar para una lista de strings. Aunque, puedo crearme un validador a mi gusto y comprobar a través de una regex que se ha introducido correctamente la lista, y que los artículos existen.

Otro planteamiento que se me ocurre es crear un tabla individual de **Complementos** en la BD, con dos campos claves, un campo artículo (el artículo que tendrá los complementos) y un segundo campo clave que  también sería una referencia de artículo, los dos enlazados a la tabla  de **Artículos** para garantizar que están dados de alta en este último. De esta manera por cada artículo, tendríamos varios registros (artículos).
Y como novato en esto, no sé cuál de los dos caminos escoger, o quizás otra alternativa.

```
from django.db import models

class Articulos(models.Model):
complementos = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=validate_comma_separated_integer_list)
```

Comment: has probado guardarlo como JSON ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo encontré. En Django existen unos tipos de campos específicos para postgresql:
[Campos específicos del modelo postgresql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). Entre ellos **ArrayField** para listas sencillas como en mi caso:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Articulo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complementos = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

También hay otro tipo de datos **JSONField** para listas de objetos, más complejas. Tienen métodos preparados para extraer la información fácilmente.